# Apache airflow issue while trying to update new script from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, airflow, mwaa

I've a very specific issue and need your help, appreciate any help in this regard.

I'm using the MWAA (AWS) airflow and the DAG details are picked up from S3.
Recently we found that one of the DAGs was not configured properly, hence we updated the script and uploaded the new version to S3 (with the changes).
After a while, the DAG changed to reflect the new changes, however, few hours later, it switched back to the old DAG. The step status was showing as 'removed'.

[image: Dag step removed status]

We've checked within our team and no one had reverted the changes and the new/changed script is still at the S3 location.

My doubt is if the MWAA has some kind of cache where it store the old script and is falling back to it? If so, any suggestions on how to clear it so the new script can take effect?

Thank you for your time

- Newbie MWAA

Comment: I would suggest to open a support case with AWS

Comment: I did already, even they are not aware of this kind of scenario.

Comment: same issue, did u find the reason or a solution to this?